# Prevent apache to free the port 80

Tags: mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have installed WAMP2.4 on windows 7 - 64bit. Its working fine and also i am able to connect it from localhost and from outside. Skype, IIS or VMware is not installed on the system. In 
"services" the mysql and apache both are set to start automatically and are in started state. All services of WAMP is working and the icon is green.

Now, the problem is, the website goes down very often. When its down, the WAMP icon is still green, mysql and apache are still in "started" state. Then I just click on "Restart all services" every time and it starts working.

When its down, I checked the "Test port 80" of Apache>Services and it says that the port is not being used. Same time when i check port 80 with "netstat" on command prompt it show the process id of apache. If i don't do any action, after some time it start working. Is there any way to set Apache not to free the port 80? Or, any batch command which check the port 80 and if its free, restart the wamp services?

Comment: can you check after adding below 2 lines to your httpd.conf

1. AcceptFilter http none
2. AcceptFilter https none

Comment: No. If apache exits/crashes, it releases port 80. Instead, try to figure out why it exits - e.g. look through error logs.

Comment: @nos, Apache is not crashed, it working and showing in "started" services and also in tast-manager's service list.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have another Apache and maybe MySQL as well, running on your system. The Apache service in WAMPServer is called `wampapache` and not `Apache` the MySQL service is called `wampmysql`. Both these service are configure to start manually and not automatically unless you have changed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard of this issue before now I come to think of it.

Try adding these 2 parameters to your `httpd.conf` file.

Put them after this line that should already exists in httpd.conf `# EnableSendfile on`

```
# AcceptFilter: Windows, none uses accept () instead of AcceptEx ()
# And do not recycle sockets between connections. This is useful
# Network interfaces for which the pilot is defective, and for
# Some network providers like vpn pilots or filters
# Anti-spam, anti-virus or anti-spyware.
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

With luck this should stop Apache from hanging, which I think is your main problem.